# How to export Selection Feature to CAD in ArcGIS 10.2.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, export, cad

This code can not be exported select feature to CAD file
[image]
`ESRI.ArcGIS.ConversionTools.ExportCAD exportCad =  new` `ESRI.ArcGIS.ConversionTools.ExportCAD();`

`exportCad.in_features = @"D:\mydb.gdb\Street";`

`exportCad.Output_File = @"C:\StreetCAD.DWG";`

`exportCad.Output_Type = "DWG_R2007";`

`exportCad.Append_To_Existing = "true";`

`Geoprocessor gp = new Geoprocessor();`

`gp.Execute(exportCad, null);`

I want to export only feature selection, who can help me!

Comment: Export the selected feature to a shape file then export the newly created file to a DWG.

Answer (score 1):

Export the selected polygons to a shapefile first. I give shapefiles to our CAD techs daily.  You can then import the shapefile into your DWG.